# How to collect objects from a doubly nested map in java 8?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I'm planning to leverage the benefits of using parallel streams in my program and I want to replace a loop like this:

```
    for (int gridY = gridYFrom; gridY <= gridYTo; gridY++) {
        for (int gridX = gridXFrom; gridX <= gridXTo; gridX++) {
            coordinates.add(Coordinate.from(gridX, gridY));
        }
    }
```

with something like this:

```
    IntStream.rangeClosed(gridYFrom, gridYTo).parallel().map(y -> 
        IntStream.rangeClosed(gridXFrom, gridXTo).mapToObj(x -> {
            return Coordinate.from(x, y);
        }
    )).collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

My problem is that here I get a `cyclic inference` error. I understand that I am supposed to return an `int` from the inner map to be compatible with the outer one but I want to return a `Coordinate` object (thus the `mapToObj` call). Is it possible to do so using `collect` and without using a `forEach` construct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want to do is these things:

First of all, when you call `map` on an `IntStream`, it still returns an `IntStream`, which isn't what you want. Instead, also use `mapToObj` for the outer loop.

Second of all, the inner loop returns an incomplete `Stream<Coordinate>`, which I assume is also not what you want. So, you'll want to call `.collect(Collectors.toSet())` on that as well.

Finally, you'll want to `flatMap` the `Stream<Set<Coordinate>>` into a single `Stream<Coordinate>`, and you can do that by using

```
stream.flatmap(Set::stream);
```

This all boils down to

```
IntStream.rangeClosed(0, 10).parallel().mapToObj(y ->
    IntStream.rangeClosed(0, 20).mapToObj(x -> 
        Coordinate.from(x,y)).collect(Collectors.toSet())
).flatMap(Set::stream).collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

EDIT:
Actually, forget the inner `collect`. Just `flatmap` to `Stream::sequential`.

You'll end up with

```
IntStream.rangeClosed(0, 10).parallel().mapToObj(y -> 
    IntStream.rangeClosed(0, 20).mapToObj(x -> 
        Coordinate.from(x, y))).flatMap(Stream::sequential).collect(Collectors.toSet())
```

Comment: Great, thanks! I figured out that I need to collect twice but the other `mapToObj` was still a problem.

Comment: Please check my edit. I completely forgot about `Stream::sequential`.

Comment: Why do use `Stream::sequential` as function to flat map the inner streams? Just use `flatMap(s -> s)`.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to collect twice. 
The problem is that `IntStream` isn't like any other stream in java, unfortunately. So, you have to convert it into a normal stream first, then you can do `flatMap`:

```
IntStream.rangeClosed(gridYFrom, gridYTo)
   .mapToObj( y -> Integer.valueOf(y) )
   .flatMap( y -> 
      IntStream.rangeClosed(gridXFrom, gridXTo)
         .mapToObj(x ->  Coordinate.from(x,y))
   )
   .collect(Collectors.toSet())
```

Comment: You can use `.boxed()` instead of `.mapToObj( y -> Integer.valueOf(y) )`